# How to access the final parent StatefulWidget class variables from its extended class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've `ExperienceCardFront` a StatefulWidget class which extends `_ExperienceCardFrontState`.

I'm trying to access the variables (marked as final and required) in `ExperienceCardFront` from its state, `_ExperienceCardFrontState`.

This is my `ExperienceCardFront`:

```
class ExperienceCardFront extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExperienceCardFront(
      {Key? key, required this.title, required this.image})
      : super(key: key);

  //the 2 variables I want to get access to from the extended class
  final String title;
  final String image;

  @override
  _ExperienceCardFrontState createState() => _ExperienceCardFrontState();
}
```

And this is my `_ExperienceCardFrontState`:

```
class _ExperienceCardFrontState extends State<ExperienceCardFront> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       //here I want to get access to the title (or image) variable from ExperienceCardFront
       child: Text(title),
    );
  }

}
```

The following error is thrown: `Undefined name 'title'`, when I try to run this code.

Comment: you just need add `widget` before call variable name on final parameter like this example `Text(widget.title)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this **

```
class _ExperienceCardFrontState extends State<ExperienceCardFront> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       //here I want to get access to the title (or image) variable from ExperienceCardFront
       child: Text(widget.title),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call widget.title

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
           //here I want to get access to the title (or image) variable from ExperienceCardFront
           child: Text(widget.title),
        );
      }
```